# SELECT calculated column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

NEW TO SQL and with ORACLE. Trying to write this SELECT statement to create a table view, but what I have doesn't translate over to Oracle. Can anyone help me decipher it and work through getting it to work in SQL Developer?

```
SELECT 
OrderItems.orderID, 
Items.itemID, 
Items.itemDescription, 
Items.itemPrice, 
OrderItems.quantity, 
OrderItems.discountPercentage,
(OrderItems.quantity*itemPrice)*(OrderItems.discountPercentage/100) AS discountPerItem, 
(OrderItems.quantity*itemPrice)-((OrderItems.quantity*itemPrice)*(OrderItems.discountPercentage/100)) AS totalOrder 
FROM Inner Join OrderItems on Items.itemID = OrderItems.itemID;
```

ERROR I am getting at the AS discountPerItem:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected 00923, 00000- "FROM
>   Keyword not found where expected"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 8 Column: 68

Comment: You forgot where to join in table `Items, OrderItems`. But i prefer do join like `Inner Join OrderItems on Items.itemID = OderItems.itemID`.

Comment: RIght now the error I am getting is at the 'AS discountPerItem'.... I have the red squiggly of death 'Syntax Error, Expected: From Identifier'

Comment: Update your question to show error output

Comment: Maybe you can rephrase like `((OrderItems.quantity*Items.itemPrice)*(OrderItems.discountPercentage/100)) AS discountPerItem`

Comment: Still same error

Comment: As i said you got error because you are not do join. I am gonna answer

Comment: I added your Inner  Join, but perhaps User Error and I don't have it in the right place

Comment: So new error? what error show up?

Comment: Still the same exact error :(

Comment: Try my query in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using old join you can try

```
SELECT 
OrderItems.orderID, 
Items.itemID, 
Items.itemDescription, 
Items.itemPrice, 
OrderItems.quantity, 
OrderItems.discountPercentage,
(OrderItems.quantity*Items.itemPrice)*(OrderItems.discountPercentage/100) AS discountPerItem, 
(OrderItems.quantity*Items.itemPrice)-((OrderItems.quantity*Items.itemPrice)*(OrderItems.discountPercentage/100)) AS totalOrder 
FROM Items, OrderItems
Where Items.ItemID = OrderItems.ItemID;
```

But i would prefer you do like this.

```
SELECT 
OrderItems.orderID, 
Items.itemID, 
Items.itemDescription, 
Items.itemPrice, 
OrderItems.quantity, 
OrderItems.discountPercentage,
(OrderItems.quantity*Items.itemPrice)*(OrderItems.discountPercentage/100) AS discountPerItem, 
(OrderItems.quantity*Items.itemPrice)-((OrderItems.quantity*Items.itemPrice)*(OrderItems.discountPercentage/100)) AS totalOrder 
FROM Items
Inner Join OrderItems on Items.ItemID = OrderItems.ItemsID;
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same exact error *FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Error from not found where means you are not doing join because you are using join in from so you need join in where. Try copy my query and run in your sql developer

Comment: Worked, I couldn't even tell you why. I thought mine looked just like yours with the portion you told me to add, but I guess not

Comment: Welcome to sql world when you need details friend. So please upvote my answer and do checklist so people know you got the answer. :)

Comment: Just to elaborate, the first query used a combination of FROM and WHERE. It's really easy to forget to join a particular table and get issues in your results. The second query in this answer uses the INNER JOIN syntax, which enforces two tables being joined and the columns to join on. It's a much better approach in my opinion.